# What's the difference between LPG and natural gas cooktops?

Tags: gas, natural-gas

I've seen a lot of cooktops, some rated to be used with LPG (liquid gas or propane) and others with natural gas. Some companies have 2 models of the same design (one for LPG and one for natural gas).

What is the difference between the two? is it just the connector type or is it a different design of the cooktop burner itself? Is it possible to 'convert' an LPG cooktop to natural gas (and vise versa) or is it a completely different design and there is no point in trying to convert?

Comment: Connector type, and different gas orifice. (Someone else should add the details.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both systems operate at different pressures. Depending on the appliance, there could be different orifices, burners, regulators, and fittings.

Depending on the appliance, a conversion kit may be available from the manufacturer. Though some appliances may not be convertible. Even with a conversion kit, it may be cost prohibitive to convert some appliances.

Comment: For the range we installed at my parent's house, it was less than $200 to covert a natural gas appliance to propane. It was just a regulator and burner venturi. Pretty straight forward. It was special order only though. I believe it was LG.

Comment: The last two ranges (stove +oven unit) we bought, both GE, came with the conversion nozzles & built-in flow control points for switching fuel type.  My impression was that most of the other well-known name brands did the same.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft While that may be true of ranges, it may not hold true with other appliances. I tried to make my answer more broad to include all appliances, since a fuel change will likely impact more than just a range.

Answer (score 0):

One major difference between the two is energy density. **LPG** (mostly propane and butane but also contains a significant amount of other stuff) **has about 2.4x the energy as natural gas** (mostly methane, but ethane and propane are also present). So, you should consider that along with the cost. If you can get natural gas for about 2.4 less (price-wise) per volume (not by pound) then you will save money. Generally, fuels are cost competetive.

One cubic foot of natural gas contains about 1,025 - 1,050 BTUs

One cubic foot of LP gas contains about 2,400 - 2,500 BTUs

However, there is a particular drawback with LPG- you need to be sure to check and clean out the evaporator/vaporizer/regulator regularly. In my humble experience, they get gunked up and stop working.

[image]

Natural gas is not as oily/gunky and generally requires less maintenance.